# How to set source and target java release in Warlber

Tags: java, jruby, warbler

I'm wonder if there is a way in the warble.rb config to set what source and target versions of java to build with? It seems like it just uses what ever jdk is active at the time. I can do this with java and jruby via the following commands but I can't figure it out for Warbler.

`jrubyc -J -source=1.6 -J -target=1.6 --java`

`javac -source=1.6 -target=1.6`

Comment: 'Warbler' is misspelled in the subject of this question.  I mention it because it may not show up in searches now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout **bytecode_version** option [1]:

```
# When set it specify the bytecode version for compiled class files
# config.bytecode_version = "1.6"
```

[1] https://github.com/jruby/warbler/blob/master/warble.rb

Comment: Thanks, it looks like my warble.rb was out of date as it didn't have this option.